# Callback as num_rows and break if statement meets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help, I have n data where is returned by ajax request to client. Each row of data I need to call an api from other app. Now I am using `callback` for that, and yes the api is success and give value as I expected. But I got some little problem. I have number of limitation for accessing the api per day, so what I want is if `callback` for api is responding some `error_code` like `out of quota` or any error code so for next row data I don't want to call the api again. My code like below:

```
$("#verifyMe").submit(function(event) {
    var isError = false;
    var formDatas = new FormData($('#verifyMe')[0]);
    // getting my row Data (SELECT * FROM table)
    $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function(kis) {
        for (var i = 0; i < kis.data.length; i++) { // loop as many row data
            // call api as long as no break
            console.log(isError); // always be false
            checking(kis.data[i].id, function(output){ // api returning object
                if(output.error_code) {
                    console.log(isError); // last value
                    isError = true; // only affect in callback bracket
                    console.log(isError); // true
                    break; // break for loop calling the api
                }
            } // end of callback bracket
            // I think the break; should goes this line but error_code will undefined bc out of callback function
        }
    }    
    });
});
```

I think the problem is because asynchronous. The `error_code` in `callback` will always `undefined/null` out of that `callback`, and `break;` will works if it is in `for loop` bracket (in example code I show it is in `callback` bracket). Sorry if my explanation is not clear enough. Thank you

Comment: You can try declaring a variable before the loop called isError = false; and if error, set to true. Then before each API call check if it's true, then break. Could that work?

Comment: in this case, use `return false;` instead of `break;`

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky I have tried that. Did you mean if I get error so isError = true right? Yeah but `if error` is in callback so `error` value only affect in callback bracket. Out there isError will always false. I edit my example code above.

Comment: @msc I also have tried `return false;` in callback but it has no effect to stop for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily implement your requirements using [Promise.each()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) of the bluebird library.
Using this function, you can execute asynchronous functions sequentially.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
...
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function(kis) {
            Promise.each(kis.data, (oneData) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    // It will be performed sequentially
                    checking(oneData.id, function(output){ // api returning object
                        if(output.error_code) {
                            reject(output.error_code); // break for loop calling the api
                        }
                        // Success case
                        resolve();
                    });
                });
            })
            .then(result => {
                // Will be called when all kis.data have been successfully processed
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Will be called when an error occurs in the kid.data
            });
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: I appreciate itm, Man. it seems way to work. Can you provide any link for practicing `reject()` and `resolve()` ?

Comment: @far1023 For basic usage of Promise, please refer to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise).